# How to reset app data in KMP Desktop App?

Tags: android, kotlin, desktop, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm used to become an Android Developer. Usually, I use "Clear Data" or "Clear Cache" in App Info to clear the data for my Android App (Usually to reset login, database, etc.)

How can I delete/clear the data in Desktop App?

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop version, there is no option equivalent to 'App info' found in Android, where you can easily clear app data. However, for desktop applications, you need to implement a method to clear data. Common approaches include implementing a code snippet to clear data upon app restart, creating a function to clear data if it's stored in a local database or local storage, implementing a mechanism to clear data stored in the cache, or setting up a command-line tool for data clearance